# Using jQuery closest() method with class selector

Tags: jquery, traversal, closest

```
$(this).closest(".fieldfilters");
```

This returns nothing for me. The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="fieldfilters" >
    <div class="filtri_ul_list">
        <ul>
            <li> <a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$(this)` is the `<a>`. As far as I understand `closest` traverses the DOM up and finds the closest match. Is there a problem with the selector being a class? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Can you provide more context for when that line of code is being executed? If it's inside an event handler function, let's see the whole thing. Also, I assume that's only a demo HTML snippet - not having any text inside your `<a>` would make it difficult to interact with.

Comment: Which element does `$(this)` refer to?

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't then `this` is probably not what you think.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tvK27/

Comment: This should work. 1) Recheck 'this'. 2) Is this the whole html? sometimes things wont work in IE if the html doesnt have closing tags. FF and Chrome try to adjust. 3) You can debug through the closest method in jQuery() and see what is really happening, this will most likely give you the issue

Comment: You're not going to get any useful answers to solve your problem until you start addressing comments. Posting a single line of code doesn't help at all, you need to include the code around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of .closest() is perfectly fine.

```
$(this).closest(".fieldfilters");
```

The most probable cause of your problem is that $(this) is not what you think it is.
Check your context to see what 'this' really is.

Comment: I used $this inside an ajax call, taht was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.fieldfilters');
```

Comment: but the closest div is the one with the class filtri_ul_list

Comment: The closest `<div>` would be `<div class="filtri_ul_list">`, and that doesn't *contain* any elements with the class `fieldfilters` so it wouldn't return anything.

Comment: ohhh maybe @Reigel is right , maybe we can use parent() for this

Comment: `$(this).closest(".fieldfilters");` this doesn't look bad. may be the issue is context and event. may be this is not at the correct place.

Comment: I have edited to indent the HTML. It should be easier to see how the elements are nested, and that `.closest(".fieldfilters")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first occurrence. 
`$(".fieldfilters:first")`

Comment: I dont want the firs occurence, I want the one closest to the element that is clicked

Comment: Hmm, your question doesn't state that!

Comment: @BorutFlis The title of the question is slightly misleading, to be honest. The question itself is clearer, but the two don't really align.