# .closest() with class name returning empty object

Tags: jquery, html

Taking a cue from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521678/using-jquery-closest-method-with-class-selector), I followed a similar approach to target an element using jQuery's `.closest()` method.

## HTML

```
<tr class="open"><td colspan="3">When 1 is clicked, target this tr</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="first-level">1</td> <!-- Click 1 -->
               <td>Some label</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="open"><td colspan="3">When 2 is clicked, target this tr</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="first-level">2</td> <!-- Click 2 -->
               <td>Some label</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="open"><td colspan="3">When 3 is clicked, target this tr</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="first-level">3</td> <!-- Click 3 -->
               <td>Some label</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

## jQuery

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.first-level', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('.open'); // this is returning empty
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/98qLw/1/)</kbd>

Edit: I can't use the `colspan` attribute to traverse the DOM as sometimes it may not even be present.

So for demonstration purposes, let's say a user clicks a `td` containing 2. So in that case, what would be the way to select the appropriate `tr`?

Comment: Thats because `.first-level` is not a descendant of an element with the class `open`

Comment: Please ,Solve console error first

Comment: So I guess searching for similar topics first and then trying out the solutions is of no use at all. Downvoters will downvote no matter what.

Comment: You need to read about `.closest()` and understand how it works. The example you cited is different from what you're doing. `.closest()` travels up the DOM -- it doesn't travel up *and* sideways. Your element with the class `.open` is a *sibling* of the element that contains the element with the class `first-level`, not an ancestor of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
 $(this).closest('td[colspan="3"]').parent().prev();
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('table').closest('tr').prev();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TTZfd/)**

Using Top level parent table:

```
$(this).closest('#example').find('.open');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs7QY/)**

Comment: `.closest('table')` hmmm

Comment: I would preffer using a function like .find('.open') instead of .prev() as the order of elements may change

Comment: @M_rk: ohh really...how is find gonna work in the case when its not the child element.

Comment: @milind-anantwar By selecting a common parent with .closest(), just like other examples. I didn't say you should leave out that part, just not use .prev()
However, at the moment there is not a realiable way of selecter the outer most table. I would suggest giving that table a class, such as .outer-table

Comment: That is because OP did not provided much info about it(outer table). that was the only workaround with what OP has provided.

Comment: The second one worked for me and I can safely use the `prev` as the structure will remain consistent in this case